# How to raise a window using fltk-rs

Tags: rust, fltk

I am trying to "raise" (draw "on top" of other overlapping windows and possibly make "active") a specific window in response to an event. [The official FLTK documentation](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#a908afc4420fd505e958f6ed394a86acc) seems to say that the `Fl_Window::show()` method is the way to do this. However, there is no corresponding `WindowExt::show()` (or any similar) method in `fltk-rs`.

There is a [`WidgetExt::show()`](https://docs.rs/fltk/latest/fltk/prelude/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.show) method, but it does not raise a window when invoked. There is also a similarly promising but similarly disappointing [`DoubleWindow::platform_show()`](https://docs.rs/fltk/latest/fltk/window/struct.DoubleWindow.html#method.platform_show) method.

What I *have* gotten to work is to call `.hide()` and then immediately call `.show()` on the window in question. This produces the desired effect of raising the window in question to the top of the pile. However, this

- Seems hacky, right? Like going around one's rear to reach one's elbow.
- Really does *hide* then *show* the window. On my Debian system running i3, this is almost unnoticeable (the flicker might just be standard window-redrawing), but under Windows this is terrible, because `.hide()`ing the window triggers a short (but oh-so-noticeable) fade-out animation (and `.show()`ing it a corresponding fade-in animation, plus there might even be a little shrink/grow action happening, too), which is bad user experience and looks like something is malfunctioning.

Here's an example:

```rust
use fltk::{
    prelude::*,
    app::App,
    enums::Color,
    frame::Frame,
    window::DoubleWindow,
    button::Button,
};

fn main() {
    let a = App::default();
    
    let mut sub_win = DoubleWindow::default()
        .with_size(128, 128)
        .with_pos(64, 64);
    sub_win.set_border(false);
    sub_win.set_color(Color::Magenta); // So you can see it clearly.
    let _ = Frame::default().with_label("Sub Window")
        .with_size(128, 128)
        .with_pos(0, 0);
    sub_win.end();
    sub_win.show();
    
    let mut main_win = DoubleWindow::default().with_label("Main Window")
        .with_size(256, 128)
        .with_pos(0, 0);
    let mut b0 = Button::default().with_label("won't work")
        .with_size(96, 64)
        .with_pos(20, 32);
    let mut b1 = Button::default().with_label("is hacky")
        .with_size(96, 64)
        .with_pos(130, 32);
    main_win.end();
    main_win.show();
    
    b0.set_callback({
        let mut sub_win = sub_win.clone();
        move |_| {
            sub_win.show();          // The FLTK docs suggest this should work.
            sub_win.platform_show(); // This also disappoints.
        }
    });

    b1.set_callback(move |_| {
        sub_win.hide();          // This combination is what
        sub_win.show();          // actually works.
    });
    
    a.run().unwrap();
}
```

If anybody knows the magic incantation I seek, I'd appreciate it.

#### Edit

I guess I didn't do enough investigation beforehand. The problem does not seem to be with fltk-rs specifically; in fact, it may not even be with FLTK; it might be specific to my X11 or window manager settings.

For example, the following C++ program exhibits the *exact same* behavior as the Rust one above:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>

Fl_Window *SUB_WIN;

void b_zero_cb(Fl_Widget *b) {
    SUB_WIN->show();
    SUB_WIN->redraw();
}

void b_one_cb(Fl_Widget *b) {
    SUB_WIN->hide();
    SUB_WIN->show();
    SUB_WIN->redraw();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SUB_WIN = new Fl_Window(64, 64, 128, 128);
    Fl_Box *sub_label = new Fl_Box(0, 0, 128, 128, "Sub Window");
    SUB_WIN->color(FL_DARK_MAGENTA);
    SUB_WIN->border(false);
    SUB_WIN->xclass("Floating");
    SUB_WIN->end();
    SUB_WIN->show();
    
    Fl_Window *win = new Fl_Window(0, 0, 256, 128, "Main Window");
    Fl_Button *b0 = new Fl_Button(20, 32, 96, 64, "won't work");
    Fl_Button *b1 = new Fl_Button(130, 32, 96, 64, "hacky?");
    win->end();
    win->xclass("Floating");
    win->show();
    
    b0->callback(b_zero_cb);
    b1->callback(b_one_cb);
    
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Several commenters report that the Rust version works as expected on their systems, and neither of the above programs work as expected on *my* system, so I'm going to assume it's an issue with my system.

If it matters, I am using X11 with the [`i3`](https://i3wm.org/) tiling window manager. (I do have it configured so that the windows in these examples are all automatically placed in the floating layer and not tiled; I'm not *that* dense.)

I'm not sure what to do with this questions. Should I just delete it?

Comment: FWIW, `sub_win.show()` in your above example is working for me on MacOS.  Do [`DoubleWindow::flush`](https://docs.rs/fltk/latest/fltk/window/struct.DoubleWindow.html#method.flush) or [`WidgetExt::redraw`](https://docs.rs/fltk/latest/fltk/window/struct.DoubleWindow.html#method.redraw) help at all?

Comment: @eggyal Interesting that it works on MacOS. `.show()` doesn't work for me on either Windows 10 or Linux/X11. (Neither do `flush` or `redraw`; I tried them again, just to make sure. Thanks for the suggestion, though.)

Answer (score 2):

On the C++ end, Fl_Widget::show() is a virtual function that should raise the window, if the variable points to a top-level window (a window with no parent). On the Rust side, I see these lines:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn Fl_Window_show(arg1: *mut Fl_Window);
}
```

which seem to indicate that there is a direct interface for calling Fl_Window::show(), and the same for Fl_Double_Window.

Comment: As Matthias said, `WidgetExt::show()` for Window and DoubleWindow actually map to `Fl_Window_show()` and `Fl_Double_Window_show()` which call `Fl_Window::show()` and `Fl_Double_Window::show()`.
It's done in the src/macros/widget.rs file via a Rust macro:
`unsafe { [<$flname _show>](self.inner) }`
where flname resolves into the FLTK type name of the widget (for DoubleWindow it's Fl_Double_Window).

Comment: @mo_al_ _obviously_ you are correct. I looked through both `fltk-rs` and your [`cfltk`](https://github.com/MoAlyousef/cfltk/tree/cc9f79bbc139ca0489e00e5c8a318f4bdf9bdae7) repo, and `Fl_Double_Window::show()` sure does look like it's getting called. I suppose the next thing to do is try an actual C++ FLTK example and see whether _it_ works as advertised. Man.

Comment: It would be interesting to know on which system sub_win.show() doesn't raise the window since I can't reproduce the problem on Windows nor KDE running X11. From what I understood is that hide then show on windows flickers, but does show not raise the window on windows? Could it be a wayland issue?

Comment: @mo_al_ Okay, so `.show()` works like it should on Windows; it still doesn't work on my Debian system, but I wrote a similar C++ test program, and it _also_ doesn't work properly on my Debian system, so I'm pretty sure it's specific to some aspect of my system: Debian 11 running X (definitely Xorg and not Wayland) and the [`i3`](https://i3wm.org/) window manager. I realize that i3 is a _tiling_ window manager, but I have it set up so that the windows in these test programs get auto-set to the floating layer (I'm not _that_ dumb).

Comment: @mo_al_ My particular case may be enough of a corner one that it I realize it may not matter to you. The flickering is just because I am calling `.hide()` and then `.show()` immediately. It's not a big deal on my system; it's way more annoying on Windows, but it looks like I don't have to do it on Windows anyway because just calling `.show()` works like it should there. Thanks for responding, though!